# vue directive binding value issue for comma decimal value

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-directives

my html code is like that====>

`<span class="custom-super-script" data-language="en" v-fraction-superscriptor="1,310.66">`

my vue directive is====>

```
Vue.directive("fraction-superscriptor", function (el, binding) {

let number = !isNaN(parseFloat(binding.value)) ? parseFloat(binding.value).toFixed(2) : 0;

number = parseFloat(number).toLocaleString(el.dataset.language || "nl-nl", { useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
});
```

But I always get 310.66 as a value instead of 1310.66. And when I check binding then I get this.

```
def: {bind: ƒ, update: ƒ}
expression: "1,310.66"
modifiers: {}
name: "fraction-superscriptor"
rawName: "v-fraction-superscriptor"
value: 310.66
```

How to fix this issue ? It only create problem for numbers greater than 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `v-fraction-superscriptor="1,310.66"`, `"1,310.66"` is evaluated as a javascript expression. Comma (,) is a valid javascript [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), that's why it returns "310" after evaluating the expression.
In your case, pass it as a string like this and you will get the correct value.

```
v-fraction-superscriptor="'1,310.66'"
```